# Change text colour on hover - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu within a .navContainer css div. Upon click, one of the `li` tags within the `ul` tag's text changes colour. However I would like to know how, using jquery, I can keep the colour of the currently selected navigation item and change the colour of the currently hovering item #d49a9a until the user clicks and the colour on the currently selected navigation item changes to #c2c0c0.

Please can you tell me how to do this!

My code so far:

CSS:

```
.navContainer ul{
    left: 10px;
    top:  20px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #c2c0c0;
    font-family: 'Terminal Dosis';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 20pt;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.navContainer {
    left: 150px;
    top: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

HTML (within body tag)

```
<div class="navContainer">
                <ul>
                    <li style="color: #d49a9a">Work</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".navContainer li").click( function() { 
                      $(".navContainer li, .navContainer li a").css("color", "#c2c0c0");
                      $(this).css("color", "#d49a9a");
                    });
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            </script>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for this take a look

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eW23E/)**

You just have to add the below class and on `li` `click` just set the color of the `li` element you `click` thats it

```
.navContainer li:hover{ 
   color:#d49a9a
}
```

JS

```
$(".navContainer li").click( function() { 
    $(this).css("color", "#d49a9a");
});
```

Comment: your solution doesn't remove the click color, once you've clicked another element. click more than one, and they all turn the click color even though they are not all the "active click" my solution addresses this.

Comment: @Francis - That is what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using this kind of markup to achieve that. You don't want jQuery at all!

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a><div class="dropdown"></div></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a><div class="dropdown"></div></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3</a><div class="dropdown"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Then add CSS like this

```
li{float:left; position:relative;width:60px; height:20px; background:#ccc; border:1px solid black;}
.dropdown{position:absolute; width:300px; height:200px; border:1px solid #ccc; background:#444; display:none;}
li:hover .dropdown{display:block;}
```

[See in action](http://jsfiddle.net/nQpNR/)

With that mark up you will have `li:hover` enabled in all the time menu is open. You should add submenus under menu tree. 
If you want have better UX you can use [jQuery hover intent plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent) to delay the hover.

Answer (score 0):

check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/ejawB/7/